# Windows 7 home x64 installer cannot boot 0xc000000d

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I'd like to temporarily install Windows 7 home on one of my computer for testing. I have `Win7_HomePrem_SP1_Hungarian_COEM_x64.iso` As far as I remember I downloaded it 3 years ago from Microsoft. I think I used this iso to install win7 on an old computer 3 years ago and it worked properly.

The current motherboard is MSI c236m, in the menu I see something like windows 7 installer support, which I enabled. After that I wrote the iso to a 16GB kingston pendrive I always use for installation. A Windows 10 installation successfully booted from it on the same computer, so the pendrive is ok.

I tried to write this win7 iso with recent rufus and I got the following error when I tried to boot from it: `file: bcd, code: 0xc000000d, message: "error occured while attempting to read boot configuration data"`. I checked the pendrive, the BCD file exists. I tried with both NTFS and FAT32 it does not affect it. Secure boot is disabled. I used GPT and MBR.

I tried with `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1`, sometimes it writes unable to read errors while extracting, but most of the times everything goes fine. It is weird.

I tried with `Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool-Installer-en-US` and I got the following error:
[image: Files copied successfully however we were unable to run bootsect to make the USB device bootable.]

I verified the sha1 checksum of the iso, it is fine.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Was the ISO checked for integrity?

Comment: @Phoenix Not sure where I can find a checksum.

Comment: Properties such as Copyright?

Comment: @Phoenix What do you mean?

Comment: Never mind, I found it here: https://pastebin.com/mrrwdDEK

Comment: I'll try with a different OS just to make sure the hardware is ok.

Comment: If you've used the same USB pendrive repeatedly for years as a bootable device, it could either be worn out a little bit, or even be damaged to the point that it'll show up in a USB port, you'll be able to copy files to and fro, but installing a boot sector on it will prove impossible. It happened to a USB stick of mine a while ago. A 4GB PNY I used to test live Linux distros. After a while, it simply wouldn't boot on a PC it knew intimately, no reason at all. Turns out it was ready for the scrapyard.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, but it is not a hardware issue.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but when you say that sometimes copying the ISO on the USB stick returns no error, and sometimes it does, I'm doubtful, especially after trying with various software known to be reliable when it comes to that specific task. You could try Etcher, which is kind of new on the market, and does a pretty thorough job, or Unebootin, which is a bit rough-around-the-edges in terms of interface, but does the job too. Just to check... EDIT: you can also fully format the USB stick, not just a quick format, a real good one.

Comment: @Didier Not copying, extracting wrote error. I booted Void Linux from the same pendrive since then. I am not sure what's wrong, probably it does not support UEFI properly and the mobo has no legacy mode for BIOS as far as I can tell. I think I give up. It would have been nice for comparison to another PC, but I can live without it.